# Taking over Windows DC as a domain user

Tags: windows, privilege-escalation, domain-controller

What do you suggest in order to take over a Windows Domain Controller, given the fact that you gained access to a domain user workstation and so you have domain user credentials?

I have domain user credentials (unprivileged user), and so far I have done things like (unfortunately to no avail):

- Enumeration against the DC (list users especially those belonging to administrator group, groups, hosts..)
- Got a kerberos ticket hash to crack offline (after running JtR for 7 full days ...no hash cracked)
- Password Spraying  against the extracted domain user list (I took advantage of the fact that the lockout policy is practically nonexistent)
- Tried to do some post exploitation (domain user workstation) work like loading incognito and tried to find at least a domain admin token ...to exploit...but nothing (no domain admin token)

Furhermore as a domain user I can access two shares on the DC.
..that's all

Given the above mentioned information, what should I do in order to get access to the DC?
Those two shares are writable shares, but I suppose nothing can be done in order to exploit that scenario

thanks a lot

Comment: What I would do: If you have user creds, you can go outside the box a bit and set up phishing infrastructure and send a couple targeted phishing emails to admins from the compromised account. Hopefully they submit their creds to the webpage.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion..phishing would be not feasible...maybe things like Bloodhound..but I don't think I would be able to get anything better than now..I tried to test if the compromised credentials would get in on at least another workstation but nothing...

Comment: What other services does that computer provide?  Have you scanned the ports for example?

Comment: you mean the DC? if so I did it and I found open ports like: 53 dns, 445 smb-sharing (it's not vulnerable to SMB v1), 88 kerberos...etc...if you mean the workstation then I tell you that I succeded in getting a meterpreter session so hashes, credentials..and so on..but from that I'm stuck when it comes to getting access on the DC...